# Create a batch script to automatically unzip music and create directory to put it in

Tags: powershell, mp3, id3, batch-file

I want to create a script that automatically unzips music albums and creates a new directory for them on Windows 7.

I'd also want the script to compare file metadata to data pulled from a certain music site to ensure the ID3 tags are filled with accurate data.

Would something like Powershell be sufficient? I'd just love a finger pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DotNetZip](http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip) will allow you to do this from PowerShell. It is not a one-liner, but the library will allow you to write the PowerShell script you need.

[Tag lib](http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp/) wille allow you to play with ID3Tag. [Example](http://huddledmasses.org/editing-media-tags-from-powershell/) :

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom( (Resolve-Path ".\taglib-sharp.dll") )
$media = [TagLib.File]::Create("C:\Users\Joel\Music\Audity\The Language I Think In-Music of My Heart.ogg")
# Write out the current album name
$media.Tag.Album 
# Set the album name to the name of the directory
$media.Tag.Album = ([IO.FileInfo]$media.Name).Directory.Name
# Save the new album name into the file
$media.Save()
```

Comment: That seems to be what I need. Time to play around. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could download [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) for your unzipping purposes.
The following command can be used to unzip the album:

```
7z.exe x -oOutputDir AlbumArchive(.zip, .rar, .7z, etc)
```

I'm not too familiar with the ID3 checkers and whatnot, so I'll defer to another for that part of your question.

Comment: Yeah I plan to use 7zip anyways. Didn't even think about parameters for it...guess that solves WHERE to put the output directory. Thanks for the input though.